# Excel/Pivot table auto sum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I am actually struggling to express what I want to achieve through just words, so I'll have to use some examples.

Here's an image of the pivot table

[image]

Basically I am looking at a pivot table showing number of customers and their value to us, ranked by each customer's individual value in this pivot.

There are 2 columns, first column shows the % of net value the individual customer accounts for the business, the second column shows the % each customer is to the total number of customers, hence why the % is the same for all accounts.

What I want is to create a filter/column/slicer that would allow some pre-determined thresholds, e.g. what % of number of customers accounts for 50% of all net value? What % of net value does the top 1% of customers make up to be?

Is there a way to do this?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Here's the data in a hopefully copiable format:

| Index Number | % of Net Value | % of Accounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3969 | 14.45% | 0.00701% |
| 15559 | 4.98% | 0.00701% |
| 11222 | 3.88% | 0.00701% |
| 10944 | 3.63% | 0.00701% |
| 6170 | 3.50% | 0.00701% |
| 17124 | 2.49% | 0.00701% |
| 2294 | 2.19% | 0.00701% |
| 15294 | 1.97% | 0.00701% |
| 14254 | 1.83% | 0.00701% |
| 2918 | 1.77% | 0.00701% |
| 13678 | 1.73% | 0.00701% |
| 6281 | 1.61% | 0.00701% |
| 2094 | 1.57% | 0.00701% |
| 18136 | 1.49% | 0.00701% |
| 17811 | 1.40% | 0.00701% |
| 15757 | 1.34% | 0.00701% |
| 3837 | 1.32% | 0.00701% |
| 11322 | 1.21% | 0.00701% |
| 7357 | 1.18% | 0.00701% |
| 471 | 1.16% | 0.00701% |
| 13077 | 1.04% | 0.00701% |
| 9081 | 0.82% | 0.00701% |
| 515 | 0.80% | 0.00701% |
| 5859 | 0.75% | 0.00701% |
| 14897 | 0.70% | 0.00701% |
| 7137 | 0.66% | 0.00701% |
| 14009 | 0.64% | 0.00701% |
| 531 | 0.63% | 0.00701% |
| 9568 | 0.63% | 0.00701% |
| 17458 | 0.61% | 0.00701% |
| 12267 | 0.61% | 0.00701% |
| 463 | 0.59% | 0.00701% |
| 7915 | 0.58% | 0.00701% |
| 466 | 0.58% | 0.00701% |
| 3650 | 0.53% | 0.00701% |
| 2995 | 0.50% | 0.00701% |
| 5984 | 0.49% | 0.00701% |
| 2016 | 0.47% | 0.00701% |
| 17813 | 0.46% | 0.00701% |
| 14809 | 0.46% | 0.00701% |
| 17613 | 0.46% | 0.00701% |
| 1346 | 0.46% | 0.00701% |
| 11624 | 0.43% | 0.00701% |
| 17904 | 0.42% | 0.00701% |
| 17502 | 0.41% | 0.00701% |
| 11332 | 0.40% | 0.00701% |
| 11635 | 0.40% | 0.00701% |
| 14412 | 0.39% | 0.00701% |
| 1553 | 0.39% | 0.00701% |
| 4877 | 0.39% | 0.00701% |

Comment: I think you'd have to first decide precisely what your 'thresholds' are, then give some examples of expected results for each of these. I would then create measures for each of these within Power Pivot (I couldn't visualize how it would work as any of a "filter/column/slicer", as you wrote).

Comment: Maybe Use two connected Separate Pivot Table. And Maybe Post the Data first then the desired result for us to understand more what you want to achieve

Comment: @joswoolley thanks for the reply. Thresholds: what % of accounts makes up the top 50%/90%/99% of the net value? It would be great if you can shed some lights on how to create these measures?

Comment: If you paste come raw data in copiable format - as opposed to pictures of the Pivot Table - with expected results then I'm sure I'll be able to help.

Comment: Hi @JosWoolley, I have added a table that is hopefully in a copiable format (I tested in excel and it seems to work). Expected results: What % of accounts makes up the top 50%/90%/99% of net value? What % of net value does the top 0.01%/0.02% makes up?

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm the expected result for one of those metrics using that dataset? What would you expect as a result for "*What % of accounts makes up the top 50% of net value*", for example (assuming you are able to manually calculate it, for example using Excel formulas)? Once I understood what the end result should be, I can then develop the necessary measure using DAX within Power Pivot.